# Funcionamiento del strtok y strcmp

Tags: c++, c

No entiendo como funciona esta función. Me lo podrían explicar en pseudocodigo paso por paso? Se que sirve para censurar pero no logro entender bien como funciona el strtok y strcmp. Saludos.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void censurar(char cad[],char pal[]){
char *aux; 
int i; 

aux=strtok(cad," ");  
while(aux!=NULL)  
{
    if(strcmp(aux,pal)) 
        printf("%s ",aux);
    else 
    {
        for(i=0;i<strlen(pal);i++) 
        printf("*");    
        printf(" ");
    }
    aux=strtok(NULL," ");   
}   
}
```

Comment: Podrías cambiar el titulo, debido que la pueden eliminar, deberías poner algo así como, **Funcionamiento del strtok y strcmp**

Comment: Dale. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### C++

`strtok` y `strcmp` son funciones que pertenecen a la cabecera `<cstring>` y se han añadido a la librería de C++ por compatibilidad con C. No es aconsejado su uso pues existen alternativas mejores y más seguras pertenecientes a la [stl](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library).

#### `std::strtok`

Se usa para un proceso conocido como [*tokenization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization_(lexical_analysis)), que es el proceso de dividir una cadena de texto en palabras, frases, simbolos u otro grupo de elementos, cada elemento recibe el nombre de *token*.

Recibe un puntero al primer caracter de la cadena a *tokenizar* y un puntero al primer caracter de la cadena a usar como delimitador:

```
char* strtok( char* cadena_a_tokenizar, const char* delimitador );
```

El resultado es un puntero al primer caracter después del primer delimitador encontrado, o `0` (`NULL`) si el delimitador no se encuentra. Así que este código:

```
char cadena[100] = "patatas#fritas#con#ketchup#y#mayonesa";

char *token = std::strtok(input, "#");
while (token)
{
    std::cout << token << ' ';
    token = std::strtok(NULL, "#");
}
```

Muestra:

> ```
> patatas fritas con ketchup y mayonesa
> ```

Hay que tener en cuenta que `strtok` modifica la `cadena_a_tokenizar` escribiendo `0` (`NULL`) en la cadena a medida que va encontrando *tokens* y que `strtok` no es segura para usar en [concurrencia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrencia_(inform%C3%A1tica)).

#### `std::strcmp`

Es una función de comparación de cadenas de caracteres, recibe un puntero al primer caracter a comparar de la primera cadena y un puntero al primer caracter a comparar de la segunda cadena. El resultado es un número entero:

```
int strcmp( const char *cadena_izquierda, const char *cadena_derecha );
```

El resultado puede obtiener los valores `-1`, `0` o `1` dependiendo del resultado de la comparación: `cadena_izquierda` menor a `cadena_derecha`, `cadena_izquierda` y `cadena_derecha` iguales o `cadena_izquierda` mayor a `cadena_derecha` respectivamente.

La manera en que se determina si una cadena es menor o mayor a otra es usando [orden lexicográfico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orden_lexicogr%C3%A1fico) y generalmente se usa el [valor ASCII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) de cada uno de los caracteres para este fin; es decir: el algoritmo es sensible a mayúsculas/minúsculas, así pues la cadena:

> ```
> PATATAS FRITAS CON KETCHUP Y MAYONESA
> ```

Es menor que la cadena:

> ```
> patatas fritas con ketchup y mayonesa
> ```

Porque las letras [mayúsculas tienen un valor ASCII menor que las minúsculas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Caracteres_imprimibles_ASCII): [image]

Se requiere que tanto `cadena_izquierda` como `cadena_derecha` sean cadenas de caracteres finalizadas con un caracter nulo, en caso contrario el comportamiento de la función será indefinido.

### C

`strtok` y `strcmp` son funciones que pertenecen a la cabecera `<string.h>` y funcionan de la misma manera que la ya descrita en la sección C++<sup>1</sup>; existen versiones seguras de ambas funciones a las que se les ha añadido el sufijo `_s` o se les limita la cantidad de caracteres a tratar:

#### `strtok_s`

Es la versión *segura* de `strtok` que añade parámetros que facilitan el control y ayudan a detectar o evitar errores:

```
char *strtok_s(char *restrict cadena_a_tokenizar, rsize_t *restrict maximo,
  const char *restrict delimitador, char **restrict estado);
```

Los parametros de `cadena_a_tokenizar` y `delimitador` funcionan igual que la versión de C++ ya descrita<sup>1</sup>.

El parametro `maximo` debe apuntar a una variable que contenga la longitud de `cadena_a_tokenizar`, la función `strtok_s` irá modificando dicha variable con los caracteres que quedan por examinar.

El parametro `estado` es un puntero a un caracter en que la función `strtok_s` irá guardando su estado interno.

Estas mejoras hacen que `strtok_s` sea más segura y hace posible usarla en contextos de concurrencia.

#### `strncmp`

Es la versión *segura* de `strcmp` que añade un parámetro con el número máximo de caracteres a comparar:

```
int strncmp( const char *cadena_izquierda, const char *cadena_derecha, size_t maximo );
```

Esto hace que la función sea más segura de usar, por lo demás se comporta de la misma manera que la versión de C++ ya descrita<sup>1</sup>.

#### Anexo: el cualificador `restrict`.

El cualificador `restrict` visto en la función `strtok_s` es un cualificador exclusivo de C que se usa sobre punteros. Indica que para el puntero cualificado como `restrict` (o cualquier dirección obtenida mediante [aritmética de punteros](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puntero_(inform%C3%A1tica)#Punteros_con_tipo_y_fundici.C3.B3n) a traves de él), durante todo su ciclo de vida será usado para acceder al objeto al que apunta; esto puede ayudar al compilador a realizar optimizaciones.

---

<sup>1</sup>En realidad es al reves, la versión C++ funciona igual que la de C pues estas funciones pertenecen a C.