# ¿Cómo obtener una secuencia de números por línea?

Tags: c++, pilas

Quiero obtener unos números introducidos por teclado, separados por espacios y guardarlos en una pila.

Ejemplo:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 <- una pila  
11 14 1 12 13 <- otra pila
1 11 2 2 3 3 4 4 <- otra
...
```

Tengo esto, pero de esta forma no sé cómo separar el `string` en varios `int`:

```
string s;
while(getline(cin, s)){

}
```

Comment: La función para separar una cadena en sub-cadenas es `strtok()`. Puedes leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29469/funcionamiento-del-strtok-y-strcmp) que la explica, e intentar usarla. Si encuentras problemas, edita tu pregunta para detallar específicamente qué problema encontraste.

Comment: No te recomiendo usar ninguna función como `strcat`, `strtok`, etc con `std::string`.

Comment: ¿Qué harías tu? Gracias.

Comment: Números en general.

Comment: Echa un vistazo a [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/161836/2742) con necesidades parecidas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He creado un **algoritmo**, pero solo funciona con ciertas reglas:

> - Todos los números introducidos deben ser dígitos dentro del size del tipo `int`.
> - Se utilizo la función `stoi` para convertir los números a enteros desde la referencia de un `string`. Quiere decir que el numero no
>     puede exceder cierta cantidad de dígitos (el limite de un `int`)
>     porque puede lanzarte una excepción.
> - El input puede aceptar cualquier cantidad de espacios que separen los numeros. Es decir, los numeros pueden estar separados por 1 o mas
>     espacios.
> - Acepta números negativos no menores al menor numero del tipo int.
> - Acepta cadenas que contengan numero entre caracteres. En este caso, solo tomara el primer numero que encuentre antes de un caracter que no sea un digito.

El **algoritmo** es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>  

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    string number;
    int indexOfNextSpace = 0;
    int characterValue;

    while(getline(cin, s)){

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < s.length(); ){

            characterValue = s[i] - '0';

            if(characterValue >= 0 && characterValue <= 9 || s[i] == '-'){
                indexOfNextSpace = s.find(' ', i);
                if(indexOfNextSpace > 0){

                    number = s.substr(i, indexOfNextSpace - i);
                    i += (indexOfNextSpace - i);
                }
                else
                {
                    number = s.substr(i, s.length() - i);
                    i = s.length();
                }

               // print number as int
               cout << stoi(number) << " ";
            }
            else
                i++;
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}}
```

La lógica utilizada para el **algoritmo** es la siguiente:

> - Se itera cada caracter en el string.
> - Se evalúa si el i-esimo dígito en la posición del string es un digito entre 0 y 9, o comienza con un símbolo negativo, de lo contrario lo omite.
> - Se busca la posición del caracter `' '` entre la posición i y el length del string.
> - Si hay un espacio, tomara el `substring` comprendido entre la posición i y el espacio. Si no encontró mas espacios después de la
>     posición i, es porque el `substring` debe estar comprendido entre i y
>     el final del `string`.

**Casos de prueba:**

**input:**

```
1234 -145 1 23439911
1234 -1939          9199  2   3        1
1-2-3-1 1 1 2  3      5
hola12  1235  1 333 4 -10000
1a  2b  3c       4d       f5             g6
```

**output**:

```
1234 -145 1 23439911
1234 -1939 9199 2 3 1
1 1 1 2 3 5
12 1235 1 333 4 -10000
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

**PD**: Ten en cuenta que la solución se hizo de esta manera, porque quieres obtener los numeros como `int`. Si quisieras el resultado como `string`, elimina la función que convierte el `string` a `int` (`stoi`). Esto te permite almacenar numeros de *longitudes gigantezcas* ya que lo almacenarás como cadenas y no como enteros, y al contrario de como esta hecho ahora, no te lanzará una *excepción* al introducir un numero gigante (mayor a la capacidad de un `int`).

Comment: +1 por las molestias, pero no es necesario tanto trabajo ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar `std::stringstream`, que te lo da todo hecho:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main( ) {
  std::string cadena( "1 2 cucu 3 555 777" );
  std::stringstream ss( cadena );
  int tmp;

  do {
    ss >> tmp;

    if( ss.fail( ) ) {
      std::cout << "No es un numero!\n";
      break;
    }

    std::cout << "Numero: " << tmp << "\n";
  } while( !ss.eof( ) );

  return 0;
}
```

> Numero: 1
>   Numero: 2
>   No es un numero!

Cambiando `cadena` a:

```
std::string cadena( "1   2  3       555 777" );
```

> Numero: 1
>   Numero: 2
>   Numero: 3
>   Numero: 555
>   Numero: 777

Como ves, los espacios *extra* son correctamente ignorados.

Comment: +1 por utilizar `std::stringstream`.

Comment: Esta respuesta es mucho más concisa, corta y legible.